# SCCM report to return KB status on servers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2008, sccm

I am trying to create a custom report in SCCM which will tell me if a specific KB is installed on a pool of servers, and return a binary answer (in this case, yes or no).

The problem I have is I cannot get it to return the status of just one KB. I am running this:

```
SELECT
 SYS.Name0 'Computer',
 SYS.operatingSystem0 'OS',
 UIN.Title 'Update',
 CASE
  WHEN UIN.Title LIKE '%KB3092627%' THEN 'Yes'
  ELSE 'No'
  END 'KB Installed'

FROM v_R_System SYS
 INNER JOIN v_UpdateComplianceStatus UCS ON SYS.ResourceID = UCS.ResourceID
 INNER JOIN v_UpdateInfo UIN ON UCS.CI_ID = UIN.CI_ID

WHERE SYS.operatingSystem0 LIKE '%Server 2008%'

ORDER BY SYS.Name0
```

but I get hundreds of results for each `SYS.Name0`, one for every detected update. All records for updates which arent the desired KB have a value of `'No'` for `KB Installed`, but they are still listed. I tried `SELECT DISTINCT` to see if it got me different results, but it does not.

What I want is to determine if the KB is present, and return if it is or not. I feel like I'm not even asking the fundamental question of "Is  installed or not" with this code, but I can't think of a way to ask this differently. Is this something I should be doing in Report Builder instead of the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this on a representative data set as you didn't provide one, but I think this should do what you're trying to achieve:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s1.Name0 'Computer',
    s1.operatingSystem0 'OS',
    CASE WHEN matches.Computer IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END 'KB Installed'
FROM v_R_System s1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT s2.Name0 'Computer',
    FROM v_R_System s2
    INNER JOIN v_UpdateComplianceStatus UCS ON s2.ResourceID = UCS.ResourceID
    INNER JOIN v_UpdateInfo UIN ON UCS.CI_ID = UIN.CI_ID
    WHERE UIN.Title LIKE '%KB3092627%'
) AS matches ON s1.Name0 = matches.Computer
WHERE s1.operatingSystem0 LIKE '%Server 2008%'
ORDER BY s1.Name0
```

So this effectively returns the distinct list of all Computers and `LEFT JOIN`s this to result set of just records for the update in question for each given Computer. Therefore, when the field returned from the `LEFT JOIN` is `NULL`, the update hasn't been installed and vice-versa.

And to answer your question, I personally think it's fine to be doing this in the query (as opposed to in your report somehow) - it's where I would do it.

Comment: This is doing it, thank you very much! I was absolutely stalled dead on this issue.

Comment: Does using SELECT DISTINCT matter versus just SELECT in this case? Like does that change the output on the CASE statement or something?

Comment: It means that each `s1.Name0` value only appears once (where in reality each value could appear many times in the `v_R_System` table), which is what you want. Try removing the `DISTINCT` from your query and see what results you get. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please run this query below:

```css
SELECT DISTINCT 
 SYS.Name0 'Computer',
 SYS.Operating_System_Name_and0 'OS',
 UIN.Title 'Update',
 CASE
  WHEN UIN.Title LIKE '%KB3079343%' THEN 'Yes'
  ELSE 'No'
  END 'KB Installed'

FROM v_R_System SYS
 left JOIN v_UpdateComplianceStatus UCS ON SYS.ResourceID = UCS.ResourceID
 left JOIN v_UpdateInfo UIN ON UCS.CI_ID = UIN.CI_ID

WHERE  UIN.Title LIKE '%KB3079343%'


ORDER BY SYS.Name0
```

In my test lab, There are multiple records corresponding one KB number. This method may not be a perfect solution.
[image]

You could try the built-in report:
\Monitoring\Overview\Reporting\Reports\Software Updates - A Compliance\
Compliance 8 - Computers in a specific compliance state for an update (secondary)